# SQL Server 2012 migration to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have migrated SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014.

When I change password from the application, it got changed successfully in DB. But if I try to login its not and it will logged in with old password even though the password is not present in the DB.

We are using JDBC. Is there any cache issues?

Comment: There may be a caching or database design issue with the application, but it's highly unlikely that there would be an issue with SQL Server that would cause it to return data that is incorrect, particularly if you've installed updates.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  This sentence *changed successfully in DB* seems to contradict this one *password is not present in the DB*.  Can you include and any error messages you recieve?